# Injecting ViewModel using Dagger 2 and trying to understand why @Binds doesn't work, when @Provides does

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm trying to inject a ViewModelProvider.Factory and I'm having trouble understanding why I'm not able to use a @Binds annotation.

This annotation seems to work:

```
@Binds
abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);
```

Combined with the following annotation, the project compiles:

```
@Provides
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(MyViewModel.class)
static ViewModel MyViewModel(){
    return new MyViewModel();
}
```

However, if the above code is replaced with the following:

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(MyViewModel.class)
abstract ViewModel bindMyViewModel(MyViewModel viewModel);
```

All of a sudden I get the following error message:

> ...MyViewModel cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an
>   @Provides-annotated method.

Can someone explain why the first case works and the second doesn't? As I've understood @Binds, it should create a class of the return type, of the concrete implementation that's passed as a parameter.

Comment: You need to annotate constructor of MyViewModel with `@Inject` annotation

Comment: This works, thanks! Could you explain why it works though? I'm not trying to inject anything into the constructor, which is empty anyway. So what's the function of @Inject in this case?

Comment: It's just to tell dagger that it should you use this constructor to create wanted instance.

Comment: Just seems like an odd choice for an annotation. It's like @Inject has at least two uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [egoldx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1779222/egoldx) discussed in the comments, you need to annotate your MyViewModel constructor with `@Inject` if you want Dagger to call it. As you mentioned, this means that JSR-330 defines `@Inject` to have [multiple valid uses](http://javax-inject.github.io/javax-inject/api/javax/inject/Inject.html):

- To mark constructors that the DI system should call to obtain an instance,
- To mark fields that the DI system should populate after creation and on existing instances, and
- To mark methods to call upon creation/injection, populating its method parameters from the DI system.

---

To be especially clear here, Dagger's behavior [documented in the User's Guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html#declaring-dependencies):

> Use `@Inject` to annotate the constructor that Dagger should use to create instances of a class. When a new instance is requested, Dagger will obtain the required parameters values and invoke this constructor.

...contradicts [JSR-330's definition of `@Inject`](http://javax-inject.github.io/javax-inject/api/javax/inject/Inject.html), in that public parameterless constructors are not eligible to be called:

> `@Inject` is optional for public, no-argument constructors when no other constructors are present. This enables injectors to invoke default constructors.

The discussion around this deviation is in [Square's Dagger 1 repository, issue #412](https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/412#issuecomment-44668963) and [Google's Dagger 2 issue #1105](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1105). In summary, the extra clarity was deemed useful (particularly given the number of objects that you could accidentally inject with default constructors), the extra cost of adding `@Inject` was determined not to be too burdensome, and it avoids some ambiguity about whether subclasses are eligible for injection without having to inspect the entire class hierarchy for `@Inject` fields.